# Jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, datatables

The fnGetSelected function works fine to highlight the rows of datatable in chrome, but in IE when we tend to select the cell values of the selected row using the mouse ( as we do for copying the data )then the the row highlight is removed!! It happens only in IE, iam using IE8. Can anyone help me with this problem? 
The following example of datatables also have the same problem when run with IE : http://datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html

Also this happens when we select more than one cell value, with only one cell value selected nothing weird will happen.

Answer (score 0):

did you follow the instruction correctly by given reference ?

http://datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html

I checked .this given example is work nice with even IE 6.Can you post here your codes to determine where the error shroud be ?

OR

This google code example is working fine with even IE 6 too.

[jquery-datatables-editable.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html](http://jquery-datatables-editable.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html)

But this have some more features like

**Inline cell editing**

**Select/delete rows in the table**

**Adding new records**

Try to compare borth codes to get the error or remove the extra features in the google code

Comment: Iam using IE8 and yes i have used it correctly as it works fine on chrome, the above example is giving same problem on IE8, actually the functionality is working correcltly my problem is that when i mouse select the cell values of a highlighted row then only the row gets unselected. it will happen in the above example too in IE 8

Comment: And one more thing there is no error to show as no js error or anything will appear, it just happens on IE and its happening in the above example too, and due to client restrictions i can't share any code too :(

Comment: the thing that iam trying to cope up with is occuring in below link too http://jquery-datatables-editable.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html